# How to send promo codes for beta testing without making the app available on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

Last month I've been asked to beta-test an utility app.

The developer sent me a promo code which I entered into the promo code field in iTunes. Then it downloaded the app on my Mac and I was able to sync it to my device. At that time the app was not listed on the App Store, but it definitely came from the App Store.

I haven't sent him my device UDID or anything like that upfront, so it's not an Ad-Hoc thing.

Is there a way of sending these promo codes when an app is in "pending for developer release" status? Or must I approve the app and then quickly put it into "Not For Sale" status before it appears on the App Store? What's the trick?

Question-closers: This is so programming related you wouldn't believe me if I told you *how* much. Because without an answer to this question, it will be much harder to build great apps. Having a way of sending friends promo codes to check out a beta is VERY convenient and improves the development process.

Comment: I think this is a better fit on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is not a question about an Apple gadget. Only programmers care about it.

Answer (score 2):

### iTunes Connect FAQs

> **When can I request promo codes for my latest app version?**  You will be able to request promo codes when your app version is approved
>   and the status changes to Ready for Sale. At that time, you will be
>   able to use the Promo Codes button to request promo codes.
>
> **Why don't I see a Promo Codes button for my app?**  Only iTunes Connect users with the Legal role are able to access the Promo Codes
>   button and make requests for promo codes.
>
> If you are logged in to an iTunes connect account with the Legal role,
>   and the Promo Codes button for your app is still not appearing, the
>   app may not be approved. The Promo Codes button will only be displayed
>   for approved apps with the status Ready for Sale.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean you can actually *use* the promo codes, right?

Comment: Don't know what you mean exactly. When you request promo codes, your customers can use them.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload app without releasing it (it asks after you click "ready to upload") and perhaps you can use promo codes

Answer (score 0):

With respect to promo codes, here's what I did just now:

1. I got the app into the review process, but marked it as "manual release"
2. I got the app approved (it took about 12 days)
3. I requested a bunch of promo codes from iTunesConnect, which I got immediately
4. Noticed that they didn't work on the (German) App store
5. (Maybe unrelated, maybe not: I sent a letter to iTunes to ask why they didn't work. Got no reply back yet.)
6. I went to my iTunesConnect acount, saw that I had no "Contracts in Effect" and requested a "iOS Paid Applications" contract. Which I received in a matter of an hour or so.
7. A promo code started to work.